# Critical points of rational mappings of annuli Fatou Component

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-dynamics, topological-dynamics

Given a rational function $R$ from the Riemann sphere to itself and an annulus fatou component $A_0$ we can create the chain $$A_0 \xrightarrow{R} A_1 \xrightarrow{R} A_2 \xrightarrow{R} ...$$
One can show that all $A_i$ here are also annuli.
Assuming that $R:A_i \rightarrow A_{i+1}$ is a covering map with degree >1, how does one show that $R$ has a critical point in each complementary component of each $A_i$.

(For context, I am working through Sullivan's non-wandering theorem, and this is one of the stages in his set up)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Taking for a fact that each $A_{i}$ is an annulus we can use the Riemann-Hurwitz theorem to derive your answer. The theorem reads as follows. Given two strict subsets $X,Y$ of the sphere $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ with respective connectivities $m,n$ and a proper mapping $f:X\rightarrow Y$ of degree $d$ between them, having $r$ critical points in $X$ counted with multiplicity $$ m-2=d(n-2)+r. $$

In your case, we can take $R:A_{i}\rightarrow A_{i+1}$ as a proper mapping of degree $d_{i}>1$ between topological annuli. As such, we have connectivities $c_{i}=c_{i+1}=2$, and by the Riemann-Hurwitz formula $r=0$. So, there are no critical points in $A_{i}$, meaning that at least one component of the complement of $A_{i}$ contains one critical point.

If all critical popints were contained in just one component of the complement of $A_{i}$ we can "fill" the annulus with the other in order to obtain a simply connected set $U$ in $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ upon which $R$ acts as a proper mapping of some degree $\lambda$. Applying the Riemann-Hurwitz formula on this simply connected set we get immediatly $$-1=\lambda(c'-2)+0,$$ for $c'$ the connectivity of $R(U)$. We get $\lambda=1$ which whould imply that $R|_{A_{i}}$ restricted on the annulus $A_{i}$ acts as a homeomorphism, contradicting $d_{i}>1$.

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: Ah thank you so much. That clears up a lot. I still have a couple of little questions regarding this proof if you don't mind. Firstly, when we "fill in" the annulus, we are either filling in the inner complementary component to obtain a typical disk shape, or we are filling in the outer complementary component to obtain a disk shape centered at infinity? Is this second case also simply connected, cause the way I visualise it in the plane, it looks like it has a disk missing in the centre. Also, what do you mean by R acts as a "proper mapping", does that mean it is still a covering map? Thanks

Comment: Also one more thing, this may be silly, but how do we know there must exist critical points at all?

Comment: When we fill in the annulus the choice of the bounded or unbounded complementary component does not matter. This is because we work on the sphere. Recall that a set is simply connected if its complement relative to the sphere is connected, so every time we get a simply connected set.

Comment: A map is proper if the cardinality of the pre-image of any point is constant. Equivalently in the plane, or sphere, if the inverse image of a compact set is compact. When we restrict to the constructed simply connected domain, yes R is a covering map, since we assume there are no critical points. Regarding your second comment, for any degree d>1 rational map there are 2d-2 critical points. This may bee seen by the Riemann-Hurwitz formula again, or by more elementary means, computing its first derivative.

Comment: I seeee. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Regarding the critical points, is it not that there at most 2d-2 critical points though? Meaning a map with 0 critical points is still technically feasible?