# Extending a covering map off an annulus

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, covering-spaces, complex-dynamics, topological-dynamics

Let $R$ be a map from the Riemann sphere to itself, upon which its restriction to an annulus $A$ is a covering map to another annulus $B$.

Suppose there are critical points in one of the complementary components of A. If I then "fill in" this complementary component to obtain a simply connected region, call U, doe the original covering map extend to a covering from U to another region?

If not, what conditions must hold for it to be so?

I hope this question makes sense.

For context, this problem stems off an original problem that I posted: [Critical points of rational mappings of annuli Fatou Component](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4733842/1199587)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Given a covering map $p: A \to B$, of what do you consider a critical point not in  $A$?

Comment: Well, in my context, p is a map from the Riemann sphere to itself, upon which its restriction to A is a covering map. So a critical point not in A is a point z such that p'(z)=0.

Comment: Then I suggest that you edit your question to include this really essential information.

Comment: Yea, you're absolutely right, my bad. I've made the adjustment thanks

Comment: The usual definition of a covering map includes the map being a local homeomorphism. But around a critical point, a holomorphic map isn't locally injective, so in order to be a covering map we must avoid critical points. Is this what you were asking?

Comment: Partly yes, but isn't a local homeomorphism just one of the conditions. Are the other conditions for it to be a covering map also true? Also, can we assume the degree of this covering map is constant? I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I’ve seen more than one definition of covering map used by different mathematicians, but I think being a local homeomorphism is a big part of it. It would still be surjective (onto its image) and open. About the degree of a covering map, it should be constant on connected components. But in your case, including a critical point would create problems for the degree. Think of z^n, each point, except 0 and infinity (critical points) have n preimages.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. Regarding the image of this extended map, what would that image look like? Would it just be the annulus image + one of its complement components? Or is it not that simple?

Comment: Sorry, I was away. Based on my answer to your other question, it will cover completely whichever component it touches, but it can be more. Think of the example of z^2 and take a small annulus around 1. The inside is mapped inside a small annulus as well, but the outside will map to the entire sphere (something like 4 is mapped to 16 which is outside and -1 is outside but is mapped to the inside). I hope this makes things clearer